# Woocommerce categories displayed on every category and shopping page

Tags: plugins, categories, woocommerce-offtopic, e-commerce, bug

Since we updated to the latest version of woocommerce today we've been having a problem. On every category page and shop page it displays all of the main categories (not the sub categories) we have on the website. We've tried putting the display type on categories from default to all the other options, but not one seems to be doing the trick. Instead, it adds the subcategories on top of the main categories on the shopping page. Is anyone else having the same problem or know how to fix this?

Comment: the last version WooCommerce 3.3 has a bug with the categories display and this will be corrected with the version 3.3.1 (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wc-3-3-issues-with-categories-displaying-in-shop/). Have you the problem with this version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved be installing an older Woocommerce version (3.2.6). All the wrong categories are gone now and everything is back as it supposed to be.